# Excel Pivot table Graphs

Tags: excel, graph, pivot-table

I have a [Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLTpV.png) looking like this. My question is, how do I calculate a percentage of TRUE/FALSE to Grand Total of each row? My play after that is to display the percentage of completion in Graphs. The catch is, that the number of rows is not static, it dynamically changes every week, so one week I might have 5, like I have now, and some other week I might have 7 or more, is it possible to create number of graphs depending on the percentage and rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out looks like this. Changed the Sum of value to Percentage of Grand Total, getting percentage of TRUE(Completed) vs FALSE(Uncompleted). Thanks [Isolated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13118009/isolated)

[image: Percentage of completion]

Answer (score 0):

First just change how you SHOW your values in the pivot. Right click on one of the values and go to "Values Shown As", and change from No Calculation to % of Row Total.

Then create your pivot chart. If you want to only show the "True" column, well you cannot do that. But you can make the False column invisible by changing the fill/outline colors to "none". Then change the Series Overlap to 100% so that your column aligns nicely with your product label.

[image]

**EDIT**
After posting, I re-read the question. At first I thought the question was how to show only the true values. Then I realized you are asking for distinct charts for each row. Sounds like a lot of real estate, and to do so automatically would likely need VBA. You could, of course, create a bunch of dummy graphs that fill when data are populated. You wouldn't need a pivot table for this, but rather, just formulas. The trouble is dealing with blank graphs.

Comment: Thanks, changing the Value to % of Row Total is what I needed. I will do the graphs with the VBA.